# Rails 3 nested routes controller access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a nested route as:

```
resources :wsps do
    member do
     get :location
     get :password
    end

    resources :services
  end
```

I can access all the paths (e.g: new_wsp_service_path) via de services views and services controller, however, I cannot do the same using the wsp views. It says It not recognizes the action "new".

I'd like to know how can I use the new_wsp_service_path on the Wsps views as well.

I have tried to add this to the wsp controller show but still not fixes:

```
def show
    @wsp = Wsp.find(params[:id])
    @title = @wsp.name
    @services = @wsp.services
   @page_name = "overview"
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @services }
    end
  end
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are passing a `Wsp` object when you call the path helper. 
Open up the rails console (`rails c`) and try this::

```
app.new_wsp_service_path       # => ERROR!
app.new_wsp_service_path(1)    # => should work
@wsp = ...                     # get a Wsp record
app.new_wsp_service_path(@wsp) # => should work
```

I run into this error often when I forget to pass a record to the embedded route. If this doesn't solve your problem, please post the output of the commands above and also make sure your route is set up using `rake routes | grep new_wsp_service` .